# Observable Subscribe Doesnt Execute

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to display messages out of a list for 1 second at a time.  I cannot use the `interval(1000)` because I need to be able to clear a message as soon as a condition is satisfied and display the next one for 1 second.

So far I have

```
nextMessage() : Observable<any>{
    this.currentMessage.next(this.messages[this.messagePointer++]);
    return this.currentMessages;
}

subscribeMessage() : void{
    this.currentMessage.pipe(switchMap(_=timer(1000).pipe(map(x=>this.nextMessage())))).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
}
```

This currently produces nothing.  My thought was that every 1sec the `nextMessage` routine would update the `currentMessage` Observable and if it was updated in between by an outside source the Timer would be canceled and restarted.  The subscribe method currently outputs nothing however if I try this

```
this.currentMessage.pipe(tap(x=>console.log(x)),switchMap(_=timer(1000).pipe(map(x=>this.nextMessage())))).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

I see values from my data output at 1 second intervals.  Why does the tap work but not the subscribe.

EDIT

Here is a link to a [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-eh314x?file=index.ts)

Comment: sorry, what's `currentMessages`? Anyways if you could provide the full class so that this can be reproduce that would be great as I really think this is not really enough to reproduce the issue. Also what's `_=` I assume it to be a typo? The best thing would be if you could just share a stackblitz with the full example there, could you do that?

Comment: Also `tap` probably works because it is at the beginning on of the `pipe`, so it simply gets the new messages that go through the `currentMessage` stream, whilst after the `tap` you have that `switchMap` which is likely breaking things.

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz  I added a StackBlitz Demo showing what Im experiencing.  I couldnt upload my whole project but this is all that is relevant to this issue

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) , after you added the stackblitz I can see someone already put a comprehensive answer, so I guess I am not needed anymore :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue: `switchMap` is killing the observable before the inner observable emits.

Here's the flow:

1. `currentMessage` emits a message
2. `tap` logs that message
3. `switchMap` starts a timer(1000)
4. when the timer fires, you call `nextMessage()`
5. nextMessage then pushes a value onto `currentMessage`
6. **Before you move to the next line of nextMessage**, `currentMesage` emits a message (same as step 1)
7. `tap` logs that message (same as step 2)
8. `switchMap` kills the previous observable, and starts a new timer(1000)
9. we go back to `nextMessage()`, it returns an observable but it's ignored, because it was killed in the previous step
10. loop back to step 4

A simple fix would be to change `switchMap` for `mergeMap`, but don't forget to add a `take(1)` on the inner observable, because you'd only want to have just one value for that observable:

```
currentMessage
  .pipe(
    tap(x => console.log('Tap:' + x)),
    mergeMap(_ => timer(1000).pipe(
      map(x => nextMessage()),
      take(1)
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

However, this is quite hard to understand what's going on... If you'd move to a more reactive approach I think it could get simpler.

You said you can't use interval(1000) because you need to reset based on some condition. Why don't you make that condition a Subject, so that you can compose it down? Check this one out:

```
const messageResets = new Subject();

const messages: string[] = ['Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3'];
let messagePointer: number = 0;

console.clear();

messageResets.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  // Every time we need to clear the current message, we just switchMap to a new interval
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(() => messages[messagePointer++ % messages.length])
  ))
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Note: `timer(0, 1000)` is the same as `interval(1000)`, but it emits a value just at the start, whereas interval doesn't.

Usually I make subjects only to express things that are external to the stream: In this case I want to be able to clear the current message from the outside, base on a condition I don't know.

But dealing with subjects to keep some sort of internal state is always painful on the long run.